# xcode the file couldn't be opened because you don’t have permission to view it

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors, cocoapods, tvos

I have an Xcode project with Cocoa Pods installed which I added a tvOS single view app target. I shared with the tvOS target all the pod installed. 
When I build and run my iOS target everything is ok, but when I run the tvOS target I get this error

**"ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"**

So after searching on the web I found a solution to this error. If I go to the Build Settings for the tvOS target and under **Valid Architectures** I remove **arm64** and type **armv7** the error disappears **but** then when i run the project i get this:

[image]

So if I leave the arm64 I get the first error, if I remove it I get the other one...
Someone knows how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: The issue was related to my podfile: Indeed I did not import the pods for my tvOS target.